# What if SE adds a feature call "Ribbons"?

Tags: feature-request, badges

I like badges, they greatly encourage me to answer and ask more questions.
But what if we design a system called "Ribbons", ribbons are used to reward a player for his one day activities. And I design some examples.

For example,

Good Student: Asks more than 5 questions with +3 in a day
[image]

Good Teacher: Answers more than 5 questions in a day
[image]

Good Editor:Edit questions more than 10 times in a day
[image]

Night Stalkers: Answer more than 3 questions with +2 at 12:00 P.M- 6:00 A.M PST
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure we want to encourage spamming questions.  Ideally people spend quite a while researching before asking

Comment: It took a while for me to design those ribbons, please don't just simply down vote this topic.

Comment: Is it simply a badge which "looks better"?

Comment: They do look pretty, I'd prefer them as "fancy badges" such as all gold badges are displayed as ribbons on the profile

Comment: @AlvinWong Badges are awarded for a user's continual activities. While ribbons are awarded for a user's on-day activities.

Comment: @AveMaleficum I'm not sure I can see the difference. The term "on-day" doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: @RichardTingle We can edit ribbons access conditions to avoid spamming questions. Like you can't just post questions to get a ribbon, you must post good questions to get a ribbon.

Comment: How does this encourage quality activity though? Just activity is not sufficient for beta sites.

Comment: While I appreciate the design of the ribbons, I still cannot find the difference with badge. You said *badges are awarded for a user's continual activities*, but some badges are only for one-time experience (mostly bronze badges). And some badges also has similar condition (e.g. in a day) with your ribbon: exceed daily cap reputation, used 30/max votes.

Comment: @Bart Could you elaborate on that topic a little more, Sir?

Comment: @AveMaleficum I'm not asking what ribbons will do. I'm asking _how they work_, or specifically: what part of their function is different to how badges function? They seem to fulfil the same function. We have badges you can earn every time you do something (like the Nice Answer badge), _and_ badges you can earn only once (like the Supporter badge). What do ribbons do that badges don't? (Apart from look different.)

Comment: I'm voting to put this on hold as unclear, until such time that the actual functional difference between badges and ribbons is clarified.

Comment: @AveMaleficum there is some merit in what you suggest, but where those ribbons will be displayed? New tab in user profile? Give more details and we'll see. :)

Comment: @AveMaleficum - just to make things clear, the downvotes here on meta are slightly different than downvotes on other sites. DVs here indicate that people disagree with your suggestion. They are in no way a reflection of the *quality* of your post. It's clear that you put effort into these mockups but you have not made a good enough argument to include them in the gamification system.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You just warmed my heart, Sir. Well, maybe we will show those ribbons as badges?

Comment: @AveMaleficum but how exactly? Something still missing, some "link" between what you have in mind and the reality and if you can add this missing link maybe people will see what you suggest in a better light.

Comment: There isn't night in every part of the world at the same time. Night Stalkers is simply out of the question.

Comment: So, something like Winterbash, but all the time?  What makes Winterbash fun is that it's *limited* and *temporary*.  We don't need another type of badge.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I guess you're right, Sir.

Comment: I don't agree with this question, but I don't think it should be closed. Especially since it _is_ clear what this question is asking.

Comment: @Emracool: so what purpose *do* the ribbons serve then?

Comment: @Martijn I don't know what purpose they serve, but the OP is asking for them to be implemented - the OP's question is clear.

Comment: @Emracool: no, **that isn't good enough**. A feature request that doesn't state a purpose is not a feature request. *Let's turn the frobnaz purple!* Uhm, what *purpose* does that serve? Why is it better to have it purple?

Comment: @Martijn I respectfully disagree - difference between "what you're asking" and "why you're asking." But /shrug

Comment: This proposal is vague beyond anything; someone made pretty designs for ribbons but *has no idea what to use them for*. That's not a feature request; it should have been a post on a personal blog somewhere. Without a purpose these are just pretty pictures.

Answer (score 3):

These ribbons look really nice, but I'm not sure I like the idea of these being for 1 day activity.

### Some badges are already for a single day activity

Ignoring badges which are for a single event (which could be considered 1 day badges) the [Mortarboard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/50/mortarboard) badge is already for activity in a 24 hour period "Earned at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day"

### The ribbons actually look really nice but seem to be for lesser achievement

I consider many of the existing long term badges to be much higher achievements than the proposed 24 hour ribbons. For example [Legendary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/52/legendary) "Earned 200 daily reputation 150 times" seems like a higher achievement than anything you could achieve in a day.

### How about using these as an extra reward for the highest gold badges.

These could be shown in miniature form under the user card to highlight how highly regarded gold badges are (which as I say seem far more worthy of reward than any 24 hour activity). However I'm not certain these fit within the "style" of the stack exchange sites. They look a little out of place because they are quite complicated.

[image]

Comment: Those badges match your eyes, Richard

Comment: You are right, they do seem a little of the place. Maybe their color schemes are too complicated for stack exchange sites.